# Sort a text file into a list determined by mode

Tags: python, list, file, frequency

I have a text file:

```
hello my name is bill    hello there    hello there    hiya    hiya    hiya
```

Each phrase is separated by four spaces. How can I order these words (on new lines) by frequency.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For the input file you have provided, what is the expected output?

Comment: i'm not certain what you mean, but i'm looking for just a list with most frequent at the top.

Comment: You talk about phrases (`Each phrase is`) and then you ask about words (`How can I order these words`). What exactly are you looking for? Also, you have provided a sample of the text file you want to read (it has 6 phrases). What should the output look like?

Comment: It looks like hiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` for this.

```
from collections import Counter
with open("your file.txt", "r") as f:
    phrases = Counter(f.read().split("    "))

for phrase, occurrences in sorted(phrases.items(), key=lambda _: _[1], reverse=True):
    print "Phrase: {} -- Occurrences: {}".format(phrase, occurrences)
```